# Can iphone app update access the keychain if the distribution certificate has been updated?

Tags: iphone, ios, keychain

After update our iphone app can not access the keychain.

The distribution certificate has been updated, can this affect the keychain access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keychain access depends on the App Id (more precisely on the Bundle Seed Id part of the App Id): the first part of 9876543210.com.mycompany.myapp. Probably you created the new distribution certificate on a different App Id by mistake or your team provisioning profile is not the same (9876543210.*)